# Fixed side menu inside wrapper

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I have a site that is contained in a wrapper that has a max width. This site also has a fixed side menu that is toggled with a button.

My issue is having the fixed side menu to stay inside the page wrapper as fixed elements are relative to the window not the parent element.

Here is an example using `position: fixed`: **https://jsfiddle.net/okavp4p1/**

As you can see the menu is coming out from the side of the viewport, not the wrapper (grey area).

[image: Menu with fixed positioning]

I have found away around this using `position: absolute`: **https://jsfiddle.net/5q3hn1fq/**

Here you can see the menu is coming out of the wrapper. (correct)

[image: Menu with absolute positioning]

But I had to write some extra jQuery to spoof fixed positioning on scroll.

```
// Fix menu
$(window).on('load scroll resize', function() {
    navigation.find('ul').css('top', $(window).scrollTop());
});
```

But doing it this way causes glitches/lag on most web browsers. Though the example isn't to bad when scrolling but when implementing this on an actual site with tons more elements/code it becomes very obvious.

Here is what it looks like in use when scrolling down the page:

[image: Actual usage]

I have thought of disabling scrolling when the menu is open but I was just wondering if anyone can help?

Comment: I like your animated examples, but some code would really help. Instead fixing to the right edge of the screen,  use `right: 100px`. where 100px is the length from the edge of the screen to the container. You could work this out with a bit of javascript.

Comment: @JamieC Please find both JSfiddles for code: https://jsfiddle.net/okavp4p1/  &&  https://jsfiddle.net/5q3hn1fq/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is a work-around for this. you need to create a bar at the top with `position:fixed`. This bar should have `height: 1px` and no background-color so you can't see it.

then you can add your navigation inside of there, and `float:right`. when you float right, it will show up, but will be pinned to the invisible fixed bar at the top. also, you have to give the nav a width of 0 so its invisible. then you can transition its width to `100px` or whatever you want on button click.

finally, use jQuery to set its height to the height of the window on resizing of the window, and when you show it.

here's the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ahmadabdul3/pptggn6v/1/

since the bar is inside a position:relative bar, it shouldn't jump around as much (or at all)

do NOT add right or left padding to the navigation though, this will break the effect. instead, you can put a container around the nav, and make the nav width: 90% or something so it appears to have some padding.

here's an updated fiddle with how the padding should be: https://jsfiddle.net/ahmadabdul3/pptggn6v/2/

Answer (score 0):

If performance accross all browsers is the issue, you could re-write your function using plain .js instead of jquery.

I couldn't replicate the jittery movement in chrome, but the below should be put less strain on the browser.

```
$(window).on('load scroll resize', function() {
    document.getElementById('nav-list').style.top = window.scrollY + 'px';
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/hb4zsL6g/